# Techniques to simplify complicated Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Recently, I've noticed one of my stored procedures taking a lot longer to run.

I feel my question is a bit too specific to ask out right so I thought I'd ask for a solution to my problem and advice on how to simplify complicated statements.

I have a "Results" table in my SSMS database. The select query I have, generates rankings based on results.

The rankings are generated depending on the date provided as a parameter, and calculates from results from the past four years.

Results within the last year get 100% of the points they received, between a year and 2 years ago get 75%, between 2 and 3 years ago get 50%, and between 3 and 4 years ago get 25%.

I also get another calculated column called "Rank Change", this is the change of rank since the last result before the provided date.

The query is below.

As it is a complicated query and it may be difficult to simplify, how would you simplify this query, if possible?

And what techniques do you use to go about simplifying a query like this, if there are any?

```
IF (@Date < '2000-01-01')
BEGIN
    SET @Date = '2000-01-01'
END

DECLARE @LatestContestDate DATE

SET @LatestContestDate = ( SELECT TOP 1 Date
                           FROM     Results
                           WHERE    Date < @Date
                           ORDER BY Date DESC
                         )

SET @LatestContestDate = DATEADD(DD, -1, @LatestContestDate)

SELECT  Band.Name ,
        Area.Name ,
        ( ISNULL(( SELECT   SUM(R2.Points) /*Calculates points*/
                   FROM     Results R2
                   WHERE    R2.Date > DATEADD(YY, -1, @Date)
                            AND R2.Date < DATEADD(DD, 1, @Date)
                            AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                 ), 0)
          + ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(R2.Points) * 0.75 )
                     FROM   Results R2
                     WHERE  R2.Date < DATEADD(YY, -1, @Date)
                            AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY, -2, @Date)
                            AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                   ), 0)
          + ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(R2.Points) * 0.5 )
                     FROM   Results R2
                     WHERE  R2.Date < DATEADD(YY, -2, @Date)
                            AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY, -3, @Date)
                            AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                   ), 0)
          + ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(R2.Points) * 0.25 )
                     FROM   Results R2
                     WHERE  R2.Date < DATEADD(YY, -3, @Date)
                            AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY, -4, @Date)
                            AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                   ), 0) ) AS PointsTotal , /*Below Calculates rank change*/
        ( ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( ISNULL(( SELECT
                                                          SUM(R2.Points)
                                                    FROM  Results R2
                                                    WHERE R2.Date > DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -1,
                                                          @LatestContestDate)
                                                          AND R2.Date < DATEADD(DD,
                                                          1,
                                                          @LatestContestDate)
                                                          AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                                                  ), 0)
                                           + ISNULL(( SELECT
                                                          ( SUM(R2.Points)
                                                          * 0.75 )
                                                      FROM
                                                          Results R2
                                                      WHERE
                                                          R2.Date < DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -1,
                                                          @LatestContestDate)
                                                          AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -2,
                                                          @LatestContestDate)
                                                          AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                                                    ), 0)
                                           + ISNULL(( SELECT
                                                          ( SUM(R2.Points)
                                                          * 0.5 )
                                                      FROM
                                                          Results R2
                                                      WHERE
                                                          R2.Date < DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -2,
                                                          @LatestContestDate)
                                                          AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -3,
                                                          @LatestContestDate)
                                                          AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                                                    ), 0)
                                           + ISNULL(( SELECT
                                                          ( SUM(R2.Points)
                                                          * 0.25 )
                                                      FROM
                                                          Results R2
                                                      WHERE
                                                          R2.Date < DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -3,
                                                          @LatestContestDate)
                                                          AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -4,
                                                          @LatestContestDate)
                                                          AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                                                    ), 0) ) DESC ) )
          - ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( ISNULL(( SELECT
                                                          SUM(R2.Points)
                                                      FROM
                                                          Results R2
                                                      WHERE
                                                          R2.Date > DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -1, @Date)
                                                          AND R2.Date < DATEADD(DD,
                                                          1, @Date)
                                                          AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                                                    ), 0)
                                             + ISNULL(( SELECT
                                                          ( SUM(R2.Points)
                                                          * 0.75 )
                                                        FROM
                                                          Results R2
                                                        WHERE
                                                          R2.Date < DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -1, @Date)
                                                          AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -2, @Date)
                                                          AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                                                      ), 0)
                                             + ISNULL(( SELECT
                                                          ( SUM(R2.Points)
                                                          * 0.5 )
                                                        FROM
                                                          Results R2
                                                        WHERE
                                                          R2.Date < DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -2, @Date)
                                                          AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -3, @Date)
                                                          AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                                                      ), 0)
                                             + ISNULL(( SELECT
                                                          ( SUM(R2.Points)
                                                          * 0.25 )
                                                        FROM
                                                          Results R2
                                                        WHERE
                                                          R2.Date < DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -3, @Date)
                                                          AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY,
                                                          -4, @Date)
                                                          AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                                                      ), 0) ) DESC ) ) ) AS RankChange
FROM    Results R1
        INNER JOIN Band ON R1.BandID = Band.ID
        INNER JOIN Area ON Band.AreaID = Area.ID
WHERE   ( ISNULL(( SELECT   SUM(R2.Points)
                   FROM     Results R2
                   WHERE    R2.Date > DATEADD(YY, -1, @Date)
                            AND R2.Date < DATEADD(DD, 1, @Date)
                            AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                 ), 0)
          + ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(R2.Points) * 0.75 )
                     FROM   Results R2
                     WHERE  R2.Date < DATEADD(YY, -1, @Date)
                            AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY, -2, @Date)
                            AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                   ), 0)
          + ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(R2.Points) * 0.5 )
                     FROM   Results R2
                     WHERE  R2.Date < DATEADD(YY, -2, @Date)
                            AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY, -3, @Date)
                            AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                   ), 0)
          + ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(R2.Points) * 0.25 )
                     FROM   Results R2
                     WHERE  R2.Date < DATEADD(YY, -3, @Date)
                            AND R2.Date > DATEADD(YY, -4, @Date)
                            AND R2.BandID = R1.BandID
                   ), 0) ) > 0
GROUP BY    Band.Name ,
    Area.Name,
    BandID
ORDER BY PointsTotal DESC
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation for the points calculation.  Something like:

```
select (sum(case when r2.Date > DATEADD(year, -1, @Date) and r2.Date < DATEADD(day, 1, @Date)
                 then r2.points else 0
            end) +
        sum(case when r2.Date < DATEADD(year, -1, @Date) and r2.Date > DATEADD(year, -2, @Date)
                 then r2.points else 0
            end) * 0.75 +
       . . .
      )
from results r2
where r2.BandID = r1.BandID and
      r2.Date >= dateadd(year, -4, @Date)
```

Then put this in a subquery, along with a similar expression for the similar query used for the row_number.  Then reference the expression from the subquery in the `SELECT`, `ROW_NUMBER()` and `WHERE`.  This will reduce the number of subqueries from something like 16 to 1 or 2.

You can optimize this, with an index on `results(BandId, Date)`.

In SQL Server 2012+, you might be able to do what you want with cumulative sums.

Comment: You are so fast! I was just messing around on SQLFiddle to move his logic to case statements...

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say exactly how to modify your select statement without knowing how the underlying schema and table look like.  That said I would start with looking at the [execution plan](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in sql server management studio and seeing what is bottlenecking the query: Missing Indexes, Sargability, IO, Missing Stats etc.

Here is a really good [link](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/working-query-execution-plans-sql-server/) that could get you started to quickly performance tune the query: